# Synchronous way to convert byte array to image in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, binding, arrays, ivalueconverter, windows-phone-8.1

I have a StorageFile with serialized music information which I deserialize when starting the app. I need to store albumart picture, but because BitmapImage can't be serialized I use a byte array. I want to bind the byte array (which is part of a ObservableCollection) to the Source of an image. For this to work I need to convert the byte array to a BitmapImage using an IValueConverter.

My problem is that an IValueConverter is a synchronous method and I can't seem to find a synchronous way to convert a byte array in a BitmapImage...

I tried this:

```
byte[] imagedata = tag.Pictures[0].PictureData;
Debug.WriteLine("Byte array length: " + imagedata.Length.ToString());

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imagedata))
{
    // create IRandomAccessStream
    var albumartstream = ms.AsRandomAccessStream();
    albumartstream.Seek(0);

    // create bitmap and assign
    BitmapImage albumart = new BitmapImage();
    albumart.SetSourceAsync(albumartstream);

    // return
    return albumart;
}
```

This throws an exception:

```
The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread
```

The only way to solve this is to use a Dispatcher which makes the code asynchronous and therefor incompatible with the IValueConverter...

What should I do to make this work?

Comment: Can you post more code - where you implement above method? What do you want to run synchronously?

Comment: I solved the problem by binding the path of the storagefile to the imagesource :)

Answer (score -1):

I have a similar byte array and I wish to set it as image source.
I am being able to display the image using BitmapImage.

But, binding is not working. Could you please specify how to bind the byte array?

Comment: I ended up saving the image in memory and binding the absolute file path

Comment: I tried that. But its taking up too much memory! Have too many images to work with.

Do you have any idea if using the IValueConverter with async and returning Task<object> would work?

Comment: @PhilippeMaes: Finally found ways to reduce the byte array size and bind it directly (WP8.1 RunTime).



Compression: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25994558/compress-and-save-base64-image-on-windows-phone-8-1/25995145#25995145)



Binding: [link](http://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/04/15/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-image-in-a-windows-store-app/)



You could update your code too. :)