# Compress and save base64 image on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I have implemented the following solution to compress a base 64 image and get back the new base 64 string. It works fine in Windows Phone 8.0 but targeting Windows Phone 8.1 it seems that there are changes in the environment.

The `WriteableBitmap` has no constructor for a `BitmapImage` and the `WriteableBitmap` has no function `SaveJpeg`. I know that `SaveJpeg` is an extension, is there a way to add this extension to Windows Phone 8.1? Or is there any API which I can use? What do I have to change to make this 8.1 compatible? I'm kinda stuck with it here :-/

```
public static string Compress(String base64String, int compression)
{
    String compressedImage;

    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    bitmapImage.SetSource(memoryStream.AsRandomAccessStream());

    WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap(bitmapImage);

    int height = bmp.PixelHeight;
    int width = bmp.PixelWidth;
    int orientation = 0;
    int quality = 100 - compression;

    MemoryStream targetStream = new MemoryStream();
    bmp.SaveJpeg(targetStream, width, height, orientation, quality);

    byte[] targetImage = targetStream.ToArray();
    compressedImage = System.Convert.ToBase64String(targetImage);

    return compressedImage;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In WP8.1 Runtime I've used [BitmapPropertySet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmappropertyset.aspx) to define a level of compression. Here below is sample code operating on *Streams*:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Method compressing image stored in stream
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sourceStream">stream with the image</param>
/// <param name="quality">new quality of the image 0.0 - 1.0</param>
/// <returns></returns>
private async Task<IRandomAccessStream> CompressImageAsync(IRandomAccessStream sourceStream, double newQuality)
{
    // create bitmap decoder from source stream
    BitmapDecoder bmpDecoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(sourceStream);

    // bitmap transform if you need any
    BitmapTransform bmpTransform = new BitmapTransform() { ScaledHeight = newHeight, ScaledWidth = newWidth, InterpolationMode = BitmapInterpolationMode.Cubic };

    PixelDataProvider pixelData = await bmpDecoder.GetPixelDataAsync(BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8, BitmapAlphaMode.Straight, bmpTransform, ExifOrientationMode.RespectExifOrientation, ColorManagementMode.DoNotColorManage);
    InMemoryRandomAccessStream destStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream(); // destination stream

    // define new quality for the image
    var propertySet = new BitmapPropertySet();
    var quality = new BitmapTypedValue(newQuality, PropertyType.Single);
    propertySet.Add("ImageQuality", quality);

    // create encoder with desired quality
    BitmapEncoder bmpEncoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, destFileStream, propertySet);
    bmpEncoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8, BitmapAlphaMode.Straight, newHeight, newWidth, 300, 300, pixelData.DetachPixelData());
    await bmpEncoder.FlushAsync();
    return destStream;
}
```

Comment: What if you do not know the size ahead of time?

Comment: @JerryNixon-MSFT You mean that you don't know the size to which you want to scale your image?

Comment: I mean, what if you are encoding from a base64 and you don't know the height and width to set in the SetPixelData

Comment: @JerryNixon-MSFT As I look at OP's question, I think it should be possible to read the size from *BitmapImage*, before the compression and resizing.

Comment: See how you hard code 300 and 300 as the height and width? That's the problem I am attempting to solve here.

Comment: @JerryNixon-MSFT But those hard coded 300 stands for dpi not size of the image.

Comment: @Romasz Im getting exception in  `BitmapEncoder bmpEncoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, destFileStream, propertySet);` line for png image. I changed encoderid for png,but i have no idea what `PropertyType` should i give in `BitmapTypedValue` constructor, Because when i removed `propertySet`,it worked. DO you have any idea?

Comment: @Archana I'm not sure what properties should be put for png.