# How to convert image to base64

Tags: c#, windows-8.1

I want to convert an image to base64 in order to store it in Sqlite using with C#, but this code not suitable for windows 8.1 apps:

```
public string ImageToBase64(Image image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)
{
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    // Convert Image to byte[]
    image.Save(ms, format);
    byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

    // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
    return base64String;
  }
}
```

Comment: And why is it not suitable?

Comment: What problems are you experiencing?

Comment: namespace System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat does not exists

Comment: Sounds more like you are missing a reference in your project...

Comment: off course i'm not, this function runs in windows 8

Comment: @fredrik The type [`System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat.aspx) is supported in ".NET Framework" but the poster could be targeting a version of .NET for apps? If not, the assembly to refer is `System.Drawing.dll`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25994558/compress-and-save-base64-image-on-windows-phone-8-1

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen well, of course they could have some restrictions on available libraries. I've run into that enough times on Xamarin. But It's something I wouldn't expect as a limitation when developing towards a full blown windows environment...

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are asking for Windows Store APIs for this problem:

```
public async Task<string> ImageToBase64(StorageFile MyImageFile)
    {
        Stream ms = await MyImageFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
        byte[] imageBytes = new byte[(int)ms.Length];
        ms.Read(imageBytes, 0, (int)ms.Length);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
    }
```